# What is a chain in iptables?

Tags: iptables

> Iptables is used to set up, maintain, and inspect the tables of IPv4
>   packet filter rules in the Linux kernel. Several different tables may
>   be defined. Each table contains a number of built-in chains and may
>   also contain user-defined chains.
>
> Each **chain** is a list of rules which can match a set of packets. Each
>   rule specifies what to do with a packet that matches. This is called a
>   `target', which may be a jump to a user-defined chain in the same
>   table.

How shall I understand the concept of a chain?

Is a chain a fixed list of rules?

How shall I define/specify and use a chain? For example,

> ```
> -A, --append chain rule-specification
> ```
>
> Append one or more rules to the end of the selected chain. When the
>   source and/or destination names resolve to more than one address, a
>   rule will be added for each possible address combination.

In the following command is `INPUT` the name of a chain?  Is it a name that I can give arbitrarily? Does this chain have exactly two rules? Thanks.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Iptables chains are just lists of rules, processed in order. They can be one of the fixed built-in ones (`INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, `FORWARD` in the default `filter` table, some others in e.g. the `nat` table), or user-defined ones, which can then be called from others.

As the `-A` (append), `-I` (insert) and `-D` (delete) commands imply, the rules in the chains are freely editable, they're not fixed.

> In the following command is `INPUT` the name of a chain?

Yes.

> Is it a name that I can give arbitrarily?

That one isn't, it's the built-in chain that contains rules for packets entering the system (destined for processes running on the host). The other two in the default `filter` table are `OUTPUT` (packets coming from the system, obviously), and `FORWARD` (routed packets).

The [man page `iptables(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html) has the descriptions of the tables and their built-in chains (under `TABLES`).

Of course you could place any rules for input packets in an arbitrary user-defined chain, then you'd just need to add a rule to `INPUT` referring to that chain. (e.g. `iptables -A INPUT -j mychain` would jump to `mychain` and process any rules there.)

> Does this chain have exactly two rules?

We don't know that. Those two commands *append* two rules to the chain. But there might be others that were already there before those commands were run.

If you had `iptables -F INPUT` as the first command before those two, then the result would be that only those two rules remained.

See also: [How iptables tables and chains are traversed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189905/170373) which contain links to all you never needed to know about this, e.g. 
https://stuffphilwrites.com/2014/09/iptables-processing-flowchart/. (You may want to ignore the `raw` and `mangle` tables to start with, they're that often needed.)

Comment: This part is the main point I think:
> Of course you could place any rules for input packets in an arbitrary user-defined chain, then you'd just need to add a rule to INPUT referring to that chain.