# How does Linux route packets destined for another interface?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, firewall, netfilter

How are packets routed inside a single linux machine? Imagine the following setup:

```
      +--------------------+
      |  apache on         |
      |  192.168.1.30:80   |
      |    |               |
    +---+  |             +---+
    |en0|--/             |en1|    <------   packet to 192.168.1.30:80
    +---+                +---+
192.168.1.30/24       10.0.0.30/24
      |                    |
      +--------------------+

Apache is bound to 192.168.1.30
```

<s>When sending a packet to `192.168.1.30`, it is usually dropped. However, when one activates `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, the packet is routed to the far IP.</s> (Thanks [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b). for the correction.)

Sending a packet to `192.168.1.30` is accepted on the host even though it is sent to an interface with a different IP. [This is called the weak host model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model)

Since this can be a security issue, I was wondering how Linux treats the routing with respect to the firewall.

How does such a packet traverse the firewall? Will it first go through the `FORWARD` and then the `INPUT` table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How iptables tables and chains are traversed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189905/how-iptables-tables-and-chains-are-traversed)

Comment: @A.B. Thank you, that was the missing piece of the puzzle in my head. Would you like to write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I made the question's premise be correct. But for the question itself, I think user1794469's link is fine to answer it. The schematic linked in that answer shows it clearly.

Comment: If you don't want this behaviour to happen, that's a slightly different question, is that the actual question?

Comment: @A.B. No, that would be another question (e.g. this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258810). I was strictly wondering if a packet destined for an interface not directly connect would go twice through the firewall. (First `FORWARD`, then `INPUT`.)