# Netfilter: in which situation, NF_IP_FORWARD will be triggered?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

### Netfilter Hook: NF_IP_FORWARD

There are five netfilter hooks that programs can register with. As packets progress through the stack, they will trigger the kernel modules that have registered with these hooks. Then, packet will be dropped, rejected, or manipulated.

`NF_IP_FORWARD` hook is triggered after an incoming packet has been routed if the packet is to be forwarded to another host.

**In which situation, the NF_IP_FORWARD hook will be triggered? Could you please provide some usage examples in real world?**

[image]

### Reference

1. [DigitOcean: A Deep Dive into Iptables and Netfilter Architecture](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture)
2. [iptables Processing Flowchart (Updated Often)](https://stuffphilwrites.com/2014/09/iptables-processing-flowchart/)
3. [How iptables tables and chains are traversed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189905/how-iptables-tables-and-chains-are-traversed)

Comment: Hi A.B, thanks for your information. DigitalOcean also provides a nice article ["A Deep Dive into Iptables and Netfilter Architecture"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture).  I have gone though that. They explain the detail about how to process the packet. My question is more about why a packet that doesn't belong to Host A will be sent to Host A and ask this host to forward the packet.

Comment: Hi A.B, I have revised the question and removed my assumption and provided more a precise diagram.

Answer (score 0):

### [this article](https://dev.to/netikras/iptables-a-beast-worth-training-a-firewall-a-nat-router-a-port-forwarder-an-lb-anti-dos-a-logger-for-free-5157) provides an example: Router.

---

FORWARD is a different kind of chain. It gets all the traffic that originated OUTSIDE the computer and is addressed to some OTHER computer in the network but the one we are setting iptables on. Doesn't it sound like something a router would do?

If the source is not our server's IP address and the destination is not our server's IP address, then how did that packet get to our server in the first place? I can think of 2 scenarios that wuold allow this:

- network interface in promiscuous mode. This is the case for network hubs (don't use them). Network cards in promiscuous mode (more on that in another post) accept ALL the ethernet frames travelling in LAN (a way to sniff LAN's traffic that is). When promiscuous mode is disabled (default state of a NIC) network cards only accept ethernet frames that have destination_mac matching that card's MAC address. So at ETHERNET protocol level, a frame is addressed to our server, but an IP protocol packet in that frame has a different destination_address set.
- the ethernet frame destination_mac matches the router's destination_mac. This is the case for gateways.

Once the packet reaches the router, it's then a job for ARP and routing tables to find the next hop for that packet and for a conntrack module to know how to return the packet to the original requester. And so the received IP packets that have src_address and dst_address irrelevant to our server get into the FORWARD chain.

To turn a server into a router first we have to enable routing in kernel level. That's easy and it does not even require a restart: edit a file /etc/sysctl.conf and add the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And then run a command sysctl -p to reload kernel settings. Now routing per se should be enabled. It's disabled by default for security reasons as it is simple to misconfigure (or use default settings for) a firewall to turn a computer into a router. If all computers in the network were routers spreading an anonymous attack would be very easy.

Now as we have routing enabled we can go ahead and set it up.

```
1. iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 10.10.7.0/24 -j ACCEPT
2. iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.10.7.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntract --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

That's it. These two rules join two networks: 192.168.0.0/24 and 10.10.7.0/24. Any queries passed on to 10.10.7.0/24 through 192.168.0.1 as the gateway will be routed to the correct destination and responses will be returned. However, this rule restricts 10.10.7.0/24 network from accessing 192.168.0.0/24 -- that's the ctstate's job. All connections in Netfilter are being tracked (conntrack). When Netfilter is instructed to only match `--ctstate` ESTABLISHED connections it will ignore NEW connection requests. This sort of rule will only act on connections that have already been established.

To rephrase -- Netfilter only allows NEW connection from the 192.x.x.x network and only already ESTABLISHED connections can transfer data from 10.10.x.x to 192.168.x.x. Should you want to make both networks see each other remove the `-m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED` part of the rule.

**HOWEVER** keep in mind that this kind of routing requires to update routing tables on both the networks. This means that a device on 10.10.7.0/24 must have an explicit route added to routing table specifying to use our device for queries to the 192.168.0.0/24 network. And vice versa: 192.168.0.0/24 must have a route in routing table specifying that 10.10.7.0/24 network is accessible through 192.168.0.1. Otherwise, a server on a receiving network will not know how to return a response: received IP packet's SRC_ADDR header contains an IP address on another network and the server has no idea how to reach it

In case you cannot or do not want to edit routing tables yourself on one of the networks you can try out a form of NAT'ing - SNAT'ing.